# What is the best way to monitor services/applications running on Azure Virtual machines

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor

i.e. I'm looking for a way to constantly monitor my virtual machines on Azure and check if specific services (database, application) in the vm are up and running. I also want to be alerted (email) when those services are down. Since the services running on the vm are not publicly available, I am looking for a solution that will monitor their status and report from inside the vms (if that is possible).
I am open to any suggestions.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate with [Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/overview) to collect various metrics related to the application as well as database and use [alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-overview) to send notifications.